# can't play mp3 files continuously inside a loop using pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to play an MP3, but when the function recalled that is logCreater an error shows can load mp3.

The first time it played audio correctly but when it's recalled then it cant load the mp3.

The error message say's pygame.mixer.music.load cant load xxxxx.mp3 file.

The full Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Tutorials etc\ProjBack\Healthy_programmer_cli\MainModule.py", line 151, in <module>
    timCount()
  File "e:\Tutorials etc\ProjBack\Healthy_programmer_cli\MainModule.py", line 65, in timCount
    EyeExcercise.logCreater()
  File "e:\Tutorials etc\ProjBack\Healthy_programmer_cli\EyeExcercise.py", line 45, in logCreater
    pygame.mixer.music.load("Eyesound.mp3")
pygame.error: Couldn't open 'Eyesound.mp3'
```

```
import os
os.environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = "hide"
from os.path import expanduser

import time as t
import getpass
usernm = getpass.getuser()
from datetime import datetime
import pygame


def userDirFinder():
    from os.path import expanduser
    usrpth = expanduser("~")
    mainp = os.path.join(usrpth, "Documents")
    return mainp
    
def checknSetdir():
    mainp=userDirFinder()
    target_path = os.path.join(mainp,"HealthManger","Eye_Excercise_log")
    
    if os.path.exists(target_path):
        os.chdir(target_path)
    else:
        
        os.makedirs(target_path)
        os.chdir(target_path)
        
    
def getCurrentDateandTime():
    Dat = datetime.now()
    
    currentD = Dat.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") 
    currentT = Dat.strftime("%I:%M %p")
    return currentD , currentT

    
def logCreater():
        print("Countdown paused")
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load("Eyesound.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
       
        write_msg = f"Eye Excercise Done by {usernm}"
       
        while 1:
        
            try:
                print("Time for a Eye Excercise Break , After the Eye Excercise")
                usr_msg = input("Type \"Done\" to stop this alarm: ")
                
                usr_msg = usr_msg.lower()
                if usr_msg != "done":
                    raise ValueError("Invalid Answer")
                elif "done" == usr_msg:
                    checknSetdir()
                    with open("eye_excercise_log.txt","a") as fi:
                        cdat , ctim = getCurrentDateandTime()
                        fi.write(f"Date: {cdat}          Time: {ctim}          Message: {write_msg}\n")
                        # print("Log Created")
                        
                        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                        
                        break
                
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
    
            
def logReader():
         
        try:
            checknSetdir()
            
            with open("eye_excercise_log.txt","r") as fi:
                lis = fi.readlines()
                for i in lis:
                    print(i)
            input("Press to contiue")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File is not created Yet")
            input("Press to contiue")


if __name__ =="__main__":
    while True:
        logCreater()
```

Comment: Where is `Eyesound.mp3`? Is it in the same folder as your Python code?

Comment: Yes all the .mp3 files are in the same directory and even giving the full path of mp3 file not helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First time it play audio correctly but when it's recalled then it cant load mp3

After playing the music, the current working directory is changed in the function `checknSetdir`, by `os.chdir(target_path)`.

Get the current working directory at the begin of the application:

```py
import os

currentWorkDir = os.getcwd()
```

Use an absolut path to load the file *"Eyesound.mp3"*:

```py
pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(currentWorkDir, "Eyesound.mp3"))
```